# Fiberglass window exterior: rolled or extruded aluminum?

Tags: windows, aluminum

I am looking to replace my 60+ year old wooden picture windows with fiberglass ones and have boiled it down to two options (installed price):

1. [MFG 1](https://www.pella.com/ideas/windows/pella-impervia/) whom uses rolled aluminum exterior ($3600 per window)
2. [MFG 2](https://www.marvin.com/products/collections/essential/) whom uses extruded aluminum exterior ($4200 per window)

I read that extruded is much more durable than rolled, and that rolled can allow water to seep between the aluminum and window, rotting the window ([source](https://blog.franklinwindowanddoor.com/aluminum-clad-windows-differences)).  But this was discussing wooden windows, and I doubt that fiberglass windows are as prone to water damage.

Will this difference in material type greatly affect the longevity of the windows?  I don't want to replace them for a few decades.  I live in the upper Midwest of the U.S. -- colder than Chicago but warmer than Minneapolis.

Comment: "I don't want to replace them for a few decades." Yet that is probably what you will be consigning yourself to if you go with typical replacement windows. [Wood Window vs Replacement Window](https://www.oldhouseguy.com/wood-window-vs-replacement-window/)

Comment: @GlenYates here function > curb appeal.  The old windows' seals are broken, and years of condensation on the inside has grown black mold on the trim.  I opted for fiberglass over vinyl, too, to increase the durability.

Comment: @isherwood Perhaps [this](https://www.oldhouseguy.com/renewal-andersen-replacement-windows/) is a better link.

Comment: Your fiberglass windows may not be terribly susceptible to water damage, but the wood in the walls supporting them is.

Answer (score 1):

All Aluminum shapes are extruded. The word "rolled" sounded better to the advertiser. Very simple shapes like angle can be rolled. Strength will depend on thickness, alloy, and heat-treatment. The advantage of fibeglas is that it does not conduct heat as fast as aluminum. When I bought my aluminum windows, a vinyl clad was offered to reduce thermal conductivity; I think i would get vinyl clad if I was doing it again. After over 25 years , I see no deterioration  around windows.

Answer (score 1):

Aluminum shapes can be either roll-formed (using sheet aluminum stock, i.e. eavestroughs, screen frames) or extruded (formed by pressing a heated block of aluminum through a die at high pressure) to form a specific shape.
The difference is in the cost.

Rolled aluminum is designed to be snapped on to an existing profile, providing a maintenance free surface. They contribute no strength on their own.

Extruded Aluminum adds a structural component to the window frame where the extrusion is physically connected to each other, usually with some thermal breaking component from exterior to interior. This strength allows for a slimmer profile, resulting in a larger glass to frame ratio.

Fiberglass windows do not rot and transmit very little heat through their frames compared to even uPVC. They can be finished on the exterior with a good surface coating. However, they will suffer from *surface* UV degradation over time. The aluminum exterior helps maintain their appearance and minimizes this degradation.

You will expect to see the joints on roll formed cladding to open over time because of differences in expansion between materials over temperature extremes. For fiberglass, this is a cosmetic issue since fiberglass is very stable over a wide temperature range. Extruded exteriors will not open over time as their joints are mechanically fastened to maintain their structural strength.

Your choice should be balanced between appearance and the quality of the air seals used by each system. Compression sealing (i.e. Casement Windows, Tilt and Turn) is always preferred over wiping seals (i.e. Single, Double Hung, Sliding Windows). This is what will contribute to long term comfort in your home.